how to copy or read uri start with jar:nested file
my project using springboot v3.2 and compile to .jar
using dockerfile to copy into docker container and runing success.
i needs to copy or read .jar inside resource jpg to display in web
but i dont know how to copy or read / access uri "jar:nested:/ace.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/"
the static file location is "resources/static/assets/images/default.jpg"
i want to read and copy into local folder and let project can access this static file to display
the get resources' source code
the jar:nested uri

Please
Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

Does this answer your question? Spring Boot unable to serve static image from resource folder

@aled I suspect that link might give a very small clue to the OP, but this question is specifically about Spring Boot nested jars.
